# Returning data out from promise then chain

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, apollo-server

I have a class method (for `'apollo-datasource-rest'` that is supposed to fetch a `plan` from a `plan_id`.  I need to hit two endpoints and combine the data.  This works with `Promise.all([promise1, promise2])` and then passes the `user_ids` on to the next `Promise.all` method that calls the `GET /users` endpoint multiple times.  If I `console.log` out the `usersArray` that is returned, I get the array of users, but if I try to return that array, it doesn't get assigned to the `objToReturn` variable.  I also need to add data from `snapshot2` to the `objToReturn` but that is secondary.

```
  getPlanById = async ( planId ) => {
    const promise1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
      return resolve(this.get('/url1'))
    });
    const promise2 = new Promise((resolve) => {
      return resolve(this.get('/url2'))
    });    

    const objToReturn = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
      .then(([snapshot1, snapshot2]) => {
        return snapshot1.user_ids
      })
      .then((userIds) => {
        this.getUsersFromUserIds(userIds).then((usersArray) => {
          console.log(usersArray)
          // return usersArray doesn't assign to objToReturn
        })
      })
    return objToReturn
  }

  getUsersFromUserIds(userIds) {
    let userPromises = []
    userIds.forEach((uid) => {
      const promise = this.get(`/users/${uid}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 'success') {
          return response.data.user
        } else {
          return null
        }
      })
      userPromises.push(promise)
    })
    return Promise.all(userPromises).
      then((userPromiseData) => {
        return userPromiseData
      })
  }
```

Comment: You're not returning in your last then. `return this.getUsersFromUserIds...` and you need to await objecttToReturn

Comment: Sidenote: this.get () already returns a promise, so a  bunch of lines here are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise of `this.getUsersFromUserIds(userIds)`. So that the promise chain can work.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
class UserAPI {
  async getPlanById(planId) {
    const promise1 = Promise.resolve({ user_ids: [1, 2] });
    const promise2 = Promise.resolve();

    const objToReturn = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
      .then(([snapshot1, snapshot2]) => {
        return snapshot1.user_ids;
      })
      .then((userIds) => {
        // You need to return here
        return this.getUsersFromUserIds(userIds).then((usersArray) => {
          return usersArray;
        });
      });
    return objToReturn;
  }

  async getUsersFromUserIds(userIds) {
    return [
      { id: 1, name: 'a' },
      { id: 2, name: 'b' },
    ];
  }
}

const userAPI = new UserAPI();
userAPI.getPlanById(1).then((objToReturn) => {
  console.log('objToReturn: ', objToReturn);
});
```

The output in the console:

```sh
objToReturn:  [ { id: 1, name: 'a' }, { id: 2, name: 'b' } ]
```